# How to order a table based on other table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have one `table1`

```
c1  c2
a   1
a   2
a   3
b   1
b   2
b   3
```

I have one `table2`

```
c3  c4
A   I
B   II
C   III
```

If Cross Join Table1 & Table2 into Table3

```
c1  c2  c3  c4
a   1   A   I
a   2   A   I
a   3   A   I
b   1   A   I
b   2   A   I
b   3   A   I
a   1   B   II
a   2   B   II
a   3   B   II
b   1   B   II
b   2   B   II
b   3   B   II
a   1   C   III
a   2   C   III
a   3   C   III
b   1   C   III
b   2   C   III
b   3   C   III
```

If you add one column in Table1 and cross join with Table2 and insert into Table3
the order of Table3 is missing.

So my question is, how to maintain the order based on the Table1?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about the order of inserts.  You should include whichever field you want to order by in the insert and use `order by` when `select`ing the data.

Try this -

```
select *
from table3
order by c1, c2
```

That's as good as your going to get with your current schema.

Comment: sorry the order of table3 is missing... my requirement is i just want to order table3 based upon the set of table1

Comment: if i insert "b" "4" in table1 then cross join with table2 and insert into table3 i should get "b" "4" for every 7th row in table3

Comment: You would get "b" "4" three times assuming three rows in table2.  It doesn't matter what order they are inserted into the table.  When you write your query to pull the data back you will want to use an ORDER BY regardless.  Otherwise there is no guarantee what order you get the data back, regardless of the order it went in.

Comment: @user1990383 - You can't depend on that.  Row ordering in a table shouldn't matter.  You need to design your table in such a way that you can use `order by` to achieve the results you want.

Comment: Thanks to everyone... can you suggest me how to maintain this scenario... Thank you

Comment: What are the column names on table3?  How about `select * from table3 order by 1, 2`.  That should work, but it's better to replace `1, 2` with the actual column names.